# C++ Video processing frame by frame

Tags: c++, c, video

Iam stuck with a project in which iam required to write a program in C++ that gets every frame of a raw .yuv video file and calculates the Signal to Noise ratio.
Iam stuck in this and can't find where to start from .. any guide to a tutorial or anything written on how to do this ? how to read a video and get the frames of the videos in c++?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the ffmpeg libraries https://www.ffmpeg.org/about.html for extracting frames from a video stream.

There are other libraries, like OpenCV, which may also help with the image analysis part, and Windows-specific APIs.

For measuring signal:noise, you'll need a mathematical model for noise detection, like autocorrelation.